# Detect mouseover event on multiple elements (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to detect the `mouseover` event on multiple elements, preferably by class.

For example:

```html
<div class="myElement">1</div>
<div class="myElement">2</div>
<div class="myElement">3</div>
<div class="myElement">4</div>
```

```js
selectClass("myElement").onmouseover = function() {
    console.log("Detected mouse!");
}​;
```

Comment: What does `selectClass` do, and return?

Comment: @Taplar exactly - my example above is just so people understand what I need

Comment: @Nanoo if you put undefined methods in your question, we can't help you.  Because we do not know what the logic does.  Please provide that method definition so we can debug.

Comment: undefined methods? the functions aren't defined, it's just an example.

Comment: Why are you making up methods to put in your question?  Don't do that.  Just provide the information regarding what you currently have and state your problem.  Making up logic that doesn't relate to anything in your code base will just confuse everyone.

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` and then `addEventListener` in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code below you get all the elements with the classname "myElement" and loop over them. The loop adds an event listener so when you click on the element it calls the function elementClicked which in return logs "An element was clicked!" to the console.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myElement');

function elementClicked() {
    console.log("An element was clicked!");
}
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onmouseover = function() {
        elementClicked();
    };
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I will give this a go to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've been helpful

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myElement");

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].setAttribute("onmouseover", "hoho()")    
}

function hoho() {
    console.log("mouse")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".your_class").forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
         doSomeThing();
    })
    elem.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
         secondThing();
    })
});
```